# After compiling node.js to exe via nexe got: RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "start" is out of range. It must be <= "end"

Tags: node.js, exe

I try to convert a node.js app into an exe file. All error's text is below, I have no idea how to fix it, I have used pkg package but it doesn't work properly because I need dynamically change files in the app

```
internal/fs/streams.js:106
  throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(
  ^

RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "start" is out of range. It must be <= "end" (here: 48195289). Received 48195290
    at new ReadStream (internal/fs/streams.js:106:13)
    at Object.createReadStream (fs.js:1820:10)
    at Object.createReadStream (/home/ivan/main/Work/work_net/ms/mediascreen/app:192:38)
    at SendStream.stream (/home/ivan/main/Work/work_net/ms/mediascreen/node_modules/send/index.js:796:19)
    at SendStream.send (/home/ivan/main/Work/work_net/ms/mediascreen/node_modules/send/index.js:707:8)
    at /home/ivan/main/Work/work_net/ms/mediascreen/node_modules/send/index.js:774:12
    at /home/ivan/main/Work/work_net/ms/mediascreen/app:223:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
```

Comment: After reading your post, at least i knew that i was not alone. To resolve my issue, i first checked the debug network tab in browser to see which request was pending forever. It was the loading of some image. I checked the image on disk and found that i have the same image name many times in different folders, some of them were of size 0kb. I changed the 0kb images to the original and voila after re-compiling it worked.